# Do-while outputs "infinitely" when I enter a character instead of a digit

Tags: c

For practice, I'm writing a program that acts as a main menu. I want the user to choose among the options. It works fine when the user inputs an integer but when a character is entered it prints this

[image]

infinitely instead of just printing "Invalid..." then asking for another input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
        int menu_choice, User_Num, MENU, count;
        MENU=1;

        do
        {
                printf(" *---------------------------------------*\n");
                printf(" |                                       |\n");
                printf(" | 1. Individual     2. Group     3.Exit |\n");
                printf(" |                                       |\n");
                printf(" *---------------------------------------*\n\n");

                printf(" -----------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                printf("| Type '1' if you want to enter as an individual                  |\n");
                printf("| Type '2' if you want to know enter as a group                       |\n");
                printf("| Type '3' if you want to to stop the program                     |\n");
                printf(" -----------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                printf("What is your choice?");
                scanf(" %d", &menu_choice);

                if (menu_choice==1)
                {        
                        User_Num=1;
                        printf("Accepted\n");
                }

                else if (menu_choice==2)
                {
                        do
                        {
                                printf("How many users?: ");
                                scanf(" %d", &User_Num);        

                                if (User_Num<2)
                                        printf("Invalid Input. Try Again \n");
                        } while (User_Num<2);

                        printf("Accepted\n");
                }

                else if (menu_choice==3)
                {
                        printf("Good Bye and Thank You");        
                        MENU=0;                
                }

                else
                {
                        printf("Invalid Input. Try Again \n");
                }

        } while (MENU);

        getch();
}
```

Comment: You need to clean up the leftover invalid _feed_ to scanf().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `scanf` sees input that can't be parsed according to the format, then it just leaves the input in the buffer, it doesn't remove it. So if you try to use `scanf` in a loop, the next iteration `scanf` will see the exact same input which it could not parse last time, and so on.

Therefore I recommend you to read the whole line using `fgets` into a buffer, and use `sscanf` to parse your own buffer. *And* you need to check what `sscanf` returns, to know if it managed to parse anything or not.

Comment: Sorry for asking this question, so adding this would be enough or am I still missing something? char buffer[128]; fgets(buffer, 128, stdin); sscanf(buffer, "%d", &menu_choice);

Comment: @TheYellowOcean Yes that should be enough. But I still recommend you to check what [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns, to see if it could parse the number correctly or not.